# Chrome scrollbar overlapping div border by 1 pixel

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m, when a div with a 1-pixel border and a scrollbar has fractional pixel width (where the fractional part is >= 0.5) inside another div with a percentage width (< 100%), the right side of the border is sometimes hidden, depending on rounding. This seems to happen because the scrollbar's position and the right side of the div are rounded in different directions, causing the scrollbar to overlap the right side of the div by one pixel.

Is this a known bug or is there a workaround? I'm experiencing this graphical glitch inside a PhpBB template page, where the content is centered and widths are automatically calculated which has resulted in a ---.5px width div, and I've traced it down to the following minimum reproducible sample:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Test content</p>
        <p>Test content</p>
        <p>Test content</p>
        <p>Test content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHh4c/4/) — resize the window and observe the right border flicker/appear/disappear.

Comment: Interesting. Disappearing of the right border seems only to be the case when the `#wrapper` has a calculated width of `xxx.5px` or `xxx.75px`. In my experience subpixels are always kinda buggy (different results on various browsers/versions). No possibility to round the calculated width in the template?

Comment: Its not much better as you can see the scrollbar glitching out but could use `outline`? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/zHh4c/2/)

Comment: @Ruddy Much better already - would be an acceptable solution to my UI. I noticed my border-right wasn't visible in my full-size Chrome but didn't realise it had to do with window size.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett I will keep a look out for anything that could get around this question.

Comment: @MysticEarth do you know any way to force an element's width to be an integer number of pixels (while remaining auto-sized?)

Comment: @JordanTrudgett No, sadly I don't. But it seems that the `margin: auto` is causing the disappearing of the border. When removing `margin: auto` the box still gets widths of `xxx.25px`, etc. but the border doesn't disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/zHh4c/5/

Comment: The wrapper div is not part of the template that I'm changing, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As pointed out by [Rohrbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419965/rohrbs) below, my original answer doesn't seem to work! A possible solution seems to be removing the border entirely and adding `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;`. Depending on your browser support requirements this could help achieve what you need.

<del>Replacing `margin: auto;` with `padding: 0 12.5%;` on #wrapper seems to fix this.
Not sure how important having that margin auto is for your specific case.</del>

<del>http://jsfiddle.net/zHh4c/7/</del>

Comment: Nope. The overlap still occurs while shrinking the window. :(

Comment: I'm sure this worked at one point, but since it was so long ago now, maybe I was mistaken at the time.

A simple solution seems to be removing the border entirely and adding `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;`. Depending on browser support this could help achieve what you need.

Comment: Box shadow works for me. I ended up using `outline` as suggested in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167438/chrome-scrollbar-overlapping-div-border-by-1-pixel#comment33645604_22167438 

it's outside of the border, but is sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: box-shadow doesn't work for me, but outline did, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move the border to a parent "div" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I had div with scrollbar and border-right set to 2px and when I was resizing the window I had the scrollbar or don't in result I had 1px border when scrollbar was on and 2px when not.

I've fixed it by adding `3px` border and setting:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

so the scrollbar is always visible and the border has always 2px visible width.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure scroll for your needs by this options:

```
.drop::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.drop::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

}

.drop::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #d6d3d3;
  border-right: .5px solid orange;
}
```